# An Xcode iOS app project went corrupt. What can I do to reprovision the devices or remind the system that the devices are provisioned?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad

An Xcode iOS app project went corrupt.

Now Xcode on my computer does not recognize my devices as provisioned when I have tried to give existing code a new home in a new Xcode project.

What can I do to reprovision the devices, remind the system that the devices are in fact provisioned, or otherwise run an app-in-progress on my two testing devices?

I tried to search for the usual provisioning instructions, but had trouble finding them either on raywenderlich.com or StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Could be several things here, most solved by Xcode's Organizer->Devices window.  Tether your devices with the organizer window open, and wait until the green dot appears on the listing on the left. You might have to hit a button that says "Use for development." Usually provisioning profiles will be moved to the device when the app is installed.